# Filter for multiple discrete values in crossfilter

Tags: javascript, d3.js, crossfilter

Does anyone have an approach to filtering a [crossfilter](https://github.com/square/crossfilter/wiki/API-Reference) object dimension on multiple values? Something like

```
.filterExact(["cash","visa"])
```

or

```
.filter(["cash","visa"])
```

...but not the range form of it...

or

```
.filterAll(["cash","visa"])
```

...but without the clearing part.

or an equivalent workaround/approach not using

```
.filterRange(["cash","visa"])
```

??

Or am I missing something in the API?

Thanks!

Larry

Answer (score 13):

I was facing a similar problem. The way I solved it was that I wrote a filter function that would check whether the dimension lies in a particular array or not.

```js
// Array of things you want to filter
var f = ["cash", "visa"];
// Assuming "dim" is our dimension
dim.filter(function(d){
  return f.indexOf(d) > -1;
});
```

This will check if the value lies in that array and filter accordingly.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Great solution.- @ pr

Comment: Great solution!

Answer (score 2):

The following pull request looks like it would address your needs, but it has not yet been merged in.

[Multiple arguments to filter result in union of filter operations](https://github.com/square/crossfilter/pull/22)

Once merged you would be able to do something like the following.

```
data.total.filter("cash", "visa");
```

Which would result in the union of all filter criteria.

Comment: yep, got the same pointer earlier from Captain D3 himself (mbostock). Hopefully the feature will land soon. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There doesn't seem to be anything in the API, but if you want to avoid filterRange, you could to it with two basic filters and concating the results:

```
var paymentsByType = payments.dimension(function(d) { return d.type; }),
cashAndVisaPayments = Array.prototype.concat(paymentsByType.filter('cash').top(Infinity),paymentsByType.filter('visa').top(Infinity))
```

Comment: thanks, that'll get the merged elements, but unfortunately won't provide the necessary multi-filtered dimension, which in my case is referenced by multiple views. still may have to take your approach to a workaround. cheers.