# How to filter multiple values in a dc/crossfilter dimension?

Tags: javascript, dc.js, crossfilter

Let me say that I have this data and dimension:

```
var data = [
      {"fruit": "apple", "amount": "12"},
      {"fruit": "orange", "amount": "6"},
      {"fruit": "grape", "amount": "11"},
      {"fruit": "melon", "amount": "26"},
      {"fruit": "lemon", "amount": "15"}
    ]

var ndx = crossfilter(data);
var fruitDimension = ndx.dimension(function (d) {
                            return d.fruit;
                        });
```

...and now, I want to filter just "apple","lemon" and "orange" just by using code. By now, I am trying to do something like.

```
fruitDimension.filter(["apple","lemon","orange"])
```

...but it does not work it all.

- I know that the function # **dimension.filterExact(value)** works for one value.

  - If I apply # **dimension.filter(value)** passing a vector as parameter, it deals with it as # dimension.filterRange(range)
  - I could not find which filter works for different values.

references from: https://github.com/square/crossfilter/wiki/API-Reference

Someone has a hint about what I could be doing in order to filter different elements (that do not follow a range order) of a dimension?

Thanks in advance, 
Roger

Comment: Is pure js solution ok?

Comment: Hello Nenad, thanks for your fast return. I guess not my friend, because after this filter I am intending to make an dc.redrawAll() and have my charts updated according to this filter. However, if your pure js solution guarantees the crossfilter dimension set, yes, it would be ok. =)

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11060604/filter-for-multiple-discrete-values-in-crossfilter/20352385#20352385

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Crossfilter requires a custom filter function for this. dc.js supplies one.

#### Applying to a dc.js chart

If you're using a dc chart you should apply the filter via the chart's `filter` function, which has different syntax and semantics from the crossfilter dimension filter:

```
chart.filter([["apple","lemon","orange"]]);
```

Note the extra set of brackets. Weird right? I do not know how it evolved this way. Also, dc will *toggle* each value, so if you want to replace the filter, use `replaceFilter` instead of `filter`.

This is documented in the [`filterHandler` function](https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/docs/html/dc.baseMixin.html#filterHandler__anchor), which is where dc.js applies filters to crossfilter.

The chart doesn't know about changes directly to the crossfilter dimension: if you use the chart's `.filter()` then the chart will update the visual selection.

#### Directly with crossfilter

If instead you want to apply a multivalue filter directly to a crossfilter dimension, here is a function that generates a filter function for an array of values:

```
function multivalue_filter(values) {
    return function(v) {
        return values.indexOf(v) !== -1;
    };
}
fruitDimension.filterFunction(multivalue_filter(["apple","lemon","orange"]));
```

Comment: This is an old post I ran across when searching how to use a custom filter function.  I know that you can do that at runtime but is there a way to make it so that DC.js uses a custom filter function when clicking on one of the axes of a graph?

Comment: Hi @Christoph - sure, there's always a way. :) dc.js doesn't ordinarily look for clicks on the axes, so you'd select the axis elements you're interested in (ticks?) inside of a 'pretransition' or 'renderlet' handler on the chart, then add a click event handler. You might also need to mess with the CSS because it [disables pointer-events on the text by default](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/a75a421db1ec48cbac2e3d7db0e22fe83aeab888/style/dc.scss#L170). If this doesn't answer your question, please ask a new question with more detail. Doesn't sound related to this Q&A.