# Filtering on dimensions dc.numberDisplay

Tags: dc.js

I have a dimension named as "Status" (Valid / Rejected). 
And there is a field named as "Count" (numbers).

I am trying to achieve dc.numberDisplay with Total status count (Valid / Rejected) and Rejected status count (Only Rejected)?
I am trying to filter the count based on dimension fields.

I applied a filter like below code. But it doesn't work as expected.
It displays only the rejected count in both.
Any help is appreciated.

 
I went through this stack answer and didnt help [How to filter multiple values in a dc/crossfilter dimension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38920359/how-to-filter-multiple-values-in-a-dc-crossfilter-dimension)

```
                                            // *** Total Submissions Count Dimension (Number Display) *** //

var totalSubmissionsDim=wrap.dimension(function(d) { return d.REPORTING_DATE;});
var totalSubmissionsGroup=totalSubmissionsDim.groupAll().reduceSum(function(d){return d.TOTAL_SUBMISSIONS;});

                                            // *** Total Rejections Count Dimension (Number Display) *** //

var totalRejectionsDim=wrap.dimension(function(d) { return d.REPORTING_DATE;});
var totalRejectionsGroup=totalRejectionsDim.groupAll().reduceSum(function(d){return d.TOTAL_SUBMISSIONS;});

var filterDimension = wrap.dimension(function(d) {return d.MESSAGE_STATUS;});

totalSubmissionsCount
 .group(totalSubmissionsGroup)
 .formatNumber(d3.format(","))
 .valueAccessor(function(d) {return d;})
//filterDimension.filter(function (d) { return d === 'VALID' ; });

totalRejectionsCount
 .group(totalRejectionsGroup)
 .formatNumber(d3.format(","))
 .valueAccessor(function(d) {return d;})
filterDimension.filter(function (d) { return d === 'REJECTED'; });
```